# lexicaljs rich text editor customize FORMAT_TEXT_COMMAND

Tags: lexicaljs

Currently using lexicaljs rich text editor for react app. I want to implement font family that acts like underline, bold and italic. Basiclly it wrap a selected element with span with inline style font family. is there a way to add option to customize `FORMAT_TEXT_COMMAND`?

dispatchCommand:

```
<button
   onClick={() => {
       editor.dispatchCommand(FORMAT_TEXT_COMMAND, 'Arial');
   }}
>
```